# Python Copy and Past

Tags: python, python-3.x, shutil, os.path

I am trying to copy paste a file from one folder to another using the Python Shutil module and, its giving me an error, not sure what is the problem.

```
import os
import shutil

source = os.listdir("D:\Personal\TEST\SRC")
print source
destination = "D:\Personal\TEST\DEST"

for files in source:
    if files.endswith('.txt'):
        shutil.copy(files,destination)

Error:
File "C:/Users/xxx/xxx/config/scratches/test.py", line 10, 
in <module>
shutil.copy(files,destination)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\shutil.py", line 119, in copy
copyfile(src, dst)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile
with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'TEST.txt'
```

any help is much appreciated
Thanks.

Comment: seems that `listdir` returns relative paths.

Comment: change `shutil.copy(files, destination)` to `for filename in files: shutil.copy(os.path.join(r"D:\Personal\TEST\src", filename), destination)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import os
import shutil

source = r"D:\Personal\TEST\SRC"
destination = r"D:\Personal\TEST\DEST"

for file in [os.path.join(source, x) for x in os.listdir(source)]:
    if file.endswith('.txt'):
        shutil.copy(file, os.path.join(destination, os.path.basename(file)))
```

Comment: @donjacob Then please be so kind as to mark the answer as the appropriate one so the question can be considered *closed*.